# How can i remove the existing class name in angularjs without using Jquery?

Tags: angularjs, removeclass

```
<a href="#" class="removeme">Blah</a>

<div>Click on me to remove the class from anchor</div>
```

Now if i click on div the class name should remove from anchor, i dont want to use any input element.

Comment: You closed your div with a </a> tag, and a div isn't necessarily the best tag to enclose text in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-class, bind the class name to a scope var, and use ng-click to reset the var in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ng-class instead of class attribute, then only you can handle this.